# Use value baseURL in config file in TestCafe when using method navigateTo()

Tags: javascript, automation, config, ui-automation, testcafe

I'm using Testcafe for creating automation test script.
I have defined the config file with value of baseURL to navigate to that web when starting Testcafe

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe"
}
```

But for the TestCafe API have the method navigateTo and that method need parameter is url.
So have anyway the method navigateTo will use the url has been defined in config file, right now i need to put the url in that method normally like this :

```
    await t
        .navigateTo('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/');
```

Have anyone has solutions for that ?

Answer (score 0):

The `navigateTo` method can resolve a relative path from the current page. So, you can specify only the path part of the whole url as a parameter for the `navigateTo` method:

```
await t
    .navigateTo('./documentation')
```